# Get URL from Firefox browser on Ubuntu in Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, firefox

I work on Qt.
I need to retrieve URL from current Web page opened in Firefox by using Accessibility in Ubuntu 14.04. 
Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Comment: This might be interesting: [Firefox api - access from my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025298/firefox-api-access-from-my-program).

Answer (score 0):

You should Create WebSocket based Qt apps then listen on specific port and firefox add-on and connect with particular port and then only you can communicate with Firefox and Qt Application.

Please go through these links for more help.

1. [Create Qt WebSocket Based Application.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-index.html)
2. [Create add-on using the Firefox SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29)
3. [Write WebSocket client applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)
4. [Use Firefox tab api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) to get current URL and share with Qt Apps.

Comment: Do you know variant without writing add-on?